# Why this Sparql query is not working

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/People%27s_Republic_of_China> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract . 
FILTER (lang(?abstract)='en')
}
```

but if I run the same query using a `resourcename` not containing a special character then it will work.

Am i not allowed to use such words in Sparql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your query with [FactForge](http://factforge.net/sparql), and it seems to be working. Can you be more specific ? Where do you execute your query ?

Comment: I think there is some encoding problem if i user the string ecoded like People%2527s_Republic_of_China then it works but if if use it People%27s_Republic_of_China then it don't but I don't understand where did it come %2527?